# Regular expression - starting with 3 alphanumeric characters which includes at least one letter and one number, and ending with a letter

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regex that matches the following criteria:

1. 4 characters.
2. The beginning 3 characters must be alphanumeric characters, including at least one letter and one digit.
3. The last character must be a letter.

So I expect the results would be:

- case1: abcd -> no match
- case2: 234d -> no match
- case3: a23c -> match
- case4: 3abc -> match
- case5: xy23 -> no match

I tested the following regex which matches criteria 2, but still cannot find a solution to match criteria 1&3.

```
^(?!.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{3}$
```

I tried this one but it failed on case2.

```
^(?!.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{3}[a-zA-Z]$
```

How can I combine these criteria? Thanks!

Comment: You may try [`^(?=.{0,2}[0-9])(?=.{0,2}[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{3}[a-zA-Z]$`](https://regex101.com/r/iJyYah/1)

Comment: Hi Minghua, did you make up your mind which pattern to use? The longer one below or a shorter one above?

Comment: Thanks Wiktor Stribiżew, I adopted your solution eventually, but both your solutions work on my case. Thank you guys.

Comment: Please use @+username to notify us of your comments. I posted an answer below, please consider accepting (clicking the grey tick on the left) since you chose my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=.{0,2}[0-9])(?=.{0,2}[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{3}[a-zA-Z]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJyYah/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{0,2}[0-9])` - there must be an ASCII digit after 0 to 2 chars
- `(?=.{0,2}[a-zA-Z])`- there must be an ASCII letter after 0 to 2 chars
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]{3}` - 3 ASCII alphanumerics
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 1):

No need to use complicated features for 3 or 4 characters:

```
/^(?:[a-z0-9](?:[0-9][a-z]|[a-z][0-9])|[0-9][a-z]{2}|[a-z][0-9]{2})[a-z]$/i
```

or

```
/^(?:[a-z](?:[0-9][a-z0-9]|[a-z][0-9])|[0-9](?:[a-z][a-z0-9]|[0-9][a-z]))[a-z]$/i
```